# Missile-like trajectory calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, simulations, projectile

First of all I want to let you  know that I'm not a Physicist, I am a Video Game Developer. I can simulate physical and mathematical equations and can also use some built in physics.

For example I can move an object through parametric equation of projectile

$$x = vt\cos\theta$$
$$y = vt\sin{\theta} - \frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

I can get values by increasing time, $t = 0$,$ t = 1$, . . . So these values make a good projectile.

On the other hand if I use built in Physics of Game Engine then I have to only Apply some force with a 2d or 3d vector. For example I can apply force of $\vec f = 24,15,6$ with other things in hand and I can change it like **mass**, **gravity**.

So now my question is that how can I calculate $\vec f (second method)$ or $data$ to populate in first method that the body will land on a specific predefined point.

- I'm repeating the objective is to launch a projectile such that it will land on a specific predefined point?

Comment: So is your question about using Newton's law ($\mathbf F=m\mathbf a=m\dot{\mathbf v}$) to arrive at the same parametric path as the projectile equations?

Comment: Not only force, but with different factors also like mass, gravity. Note, there is no AIR resistance in Game Engine

Comment: Well mass is independent of the parametric equations, so you should not expect a change (ideally) between a 2 kg mass and a 20 kg one.

Comment: @KyleKanos But if the OP is going to give a force first and then calculate the acceleration, then surely acceleration and also initial velocity would depend on mass

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition: I said that the *parametric equations* are independent of mass, not Newton's law.

Comment: @KyleKanos I didnt say you were wrong, I just didnt want the OP to believe that his system is independent of mass

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition: Actually, they should lead to the same results because the parametrized equations come from Newton's law: $m\mathbf a=m\mathbf g\to \ddot{\mathbf r}=\mathbf g$ and solving for $\mathbf r$.

Comment: I just want to know Velocity and theta so it would land on expected point. Just like missile, first set target and then fire with calculated velocity and angle

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, I think the OP wants to give a force $\mathbf F$ for a time $t$ and accelerate it to a velocity $\mathbf v$ (initial velocity) then $\mathbf v = \mathbf F t/m$, so initial velocity and so the parametric equations would depend on mass (or have I not understood the question well?)

Comment: Yes, I want initial velocity and angle that I would put in parametric equation so that, that trajectory contains my desired point

Answer (score 0):

One of the pieces that you need is called the [*range* equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile) (assuming that you are firing from the ground):
$$
R=\frac{v^2_0\sin(2\alpha)}{g}\tag{1}
$$
So if you start with knowing $v_0,\,\alpha$, you can figure out how far it will go. But you are starting with $R$ and trying to see what pairs of $v_0,\,\alpha$ would match this, which would be quite difficult as many pairs could lead to the same $R$.

However, you say that you are applying a force for some duration, so you can use the [*impulse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29) to determine the (final) velocity:
$$
\int\mathbf F\,dt=\Delta\mathbf p=m\mathbf v_{fin}-m\mathbf v_{init}
$$
Since the projectile is initially at rest, the launch velocity would be
$$
\mathbf v_{launch}=\frac{1}{m}\int\mathbf F\,dt
$$
which, if the force is constant throughout, can be simplified to
$$
\mathbf v_{launch}=\frac{1}{m}\mathbf F\Delta t\tag{2}
$$
where $\Delta t$ is the length of time the force is applied.

So now you know the initial velocity, $v_0=\lVert\mathbf v\rVert$, and how far you want the projectile to go, $R$, so then you can solve Equation (1) to get $\alpha$.